# Missing Windows 10 original start screen and Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows-10

My HP notebook with Windows 10 Prof. started to show multiple user accounts in the log-in screen.

I tried to delete the unfamiliar accounts using *netplwiz* and other ways, and finally did a reset losing all my files eventually, (backed up, though, in an external drive, and I do have the DVDs for the OS, too.).

Now the Windows 10 OS is totally different from which I had. The start screen looks different and ugly as well, tiles are missing, and the Edge icon is missing too.

I want to get back my original start screen and Edge. What should I do? For the last  4 days I am engaged in doing everything to get back to what I had like, sfc /scannow........advanced troubleshooting etc. without any result. I have the latest BIOS and drivers and latest Windows update which is probably the most likely cause behind my woes

Comment: Unless you have a partition back-up which you can restore, your best way forward is to down-load the latest install disc, and re-install over the top, keeping your existing files and installed programs.

Answer (score -1):

You can reset Windows 10 to clean installation with option of keeping your personal data.

1. Open **Settings**
2. **Update & security**
3. **Recovery**
4. **Get started** under *Reset this PC*
5. Choose **Keep my files**

However this will wipe all program that you have installed and reset all settings to default.

Answer (score -1):

I was so perturbed that I retrieved the whole OS AFRESH from the DVD furnished with the Notebook. I have File History in an external disk. Now I am going to experiment with the process of retrieval from it.I had a system recovery Flash Drive as well. But I had no knowledge how can the restore process be executed. Hence the use of OS DVD.
It is absolutely relevant to mention here that, my Mac never fails, performs with amazing consistency over the last 5 years and all updates are regular, without any glitch, though not  " Anniversary". 
Thanks for the prompt response anyway!